# Strict Standards: Non-static method StreamComment::getCommentsHTML() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

Tags: php, joomla, static

I am using Offiria (joomla based social networking script) and when I click on the link "Show All Comments" to see all posted comments under a link, I get the following error right above the first comments. The function works so all comments expand and I can see them all but the error sits there as well.

> Strict Standards: Non-static method StreamComment::getCommentsHTML()
>   should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible
>   context in C:\Program
>   Files\Ampps\www\offiria\components\com_stream\controllers\comment.php
>   on line 31

Here is the line 31 in comment.php file:

```
public function  showall()
{
    $stream_id = JRequest::getVar('message_id');
    $html = StreamComment::getCommentsHTML($stream_id);
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    echo $html;
    exit;
}
```

I have tried disabling all error reporting options in my php.ini but the error keeps coming up. I have also tried changing the above code to "public static function showall()" but I get an error that **Strict Standards: Non-static method StreamComment::getCommentsHTML() should not be called statically**.

I would appreciate any help with this in advance.

**Here is the complete comment.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * @version     1.0.0
 * @package     com_administrator
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2011 - 2013 Slashes & Dots Sdn Bhd. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 * @author      Offiria Team
 */

// No direct access.
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

jimport('joomla.application.controller');

class StreamControllerComment extends JController
{
    /**
     *
     */     
    public function display($cachable = false, $urlparams = false){
        parent::display( null );
    }


    /**
     *  Return HTML of all
     */     
    /**public function  showall()
    {
        $stream_id = JRequest::getVar('message_id');
        $html = StreamComment::getCommentsHTML($stream_id);
        header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
        echo $html;
        exit;
    }

    /**
     *  Add message
     */                            
    public function add()
    {
        $user   = JXFactory::getUser();

        // Store stream
        $comment    = JTable::getInstance( 'Comment' , 'StreamTable' );
        $message    = JTable::getInstance( 'Stream' , 'StreamTable' );
        $message->load(JRequest::getVar('stream_id'));
        $user_id = JRequest::getVar('anon', false) ? JUserHelper::getUserId('anon') : $user->id;

        // People need to be able to read the message to add comment
        if( !$user->authorise('stream.message.read', $message) ){
            // No reason this code would ever get here!
            exit;
        }

        $comment->bind( JRequest::get('POST', JREQUEST_ALLOWRAW) );

        $comment->raw = json_encode( JRequest::get('POST', JREQUEST_ALLOWRAW) );
        $comment->user_id = $user_id;
        $comment->group_id = $message->group_id;            
        $comment->store();

        // Update group stats, if it is a group message
        if( !empty($comment->group_id)){
            $group  = JTable::getInstance( 'Group' , 'StreamTable' );
            $group->load($comment->group_id);
            $group->setParam('last_comment', $comment->id);
            $group->store();
        }

        // Trigger Notification 
        StreamNotification::trigger( 'profile_post_comment', $comment );

        // If the updated date is set further than the current date, it is a pinned stream item and shouldn't be updated
        $now        = new JDate();
        $updated    = new JDate($message->updated);
        $preventUpdate = ($updated->toUnix() > $now->toUnix()); // Check pinned item status too? For now... naa

        // Update stream stats. Recalculate the count
        $this->_recalculateCommentCount($comment->stream_id, $preventUpdate);

        // Get the HTML code to append
        $tmpl = new StreamTemplate();
        header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
        echo $tmpl->set('comment', $comment)->fetch('comment.item');
        exit;
    }

    /**
     * Delete a message
     */
    public function delete(){
        $my = JXFactory::getUser();
        $id = JRequest::getVar('comment_id');
        $oldComment = '';

        $comment    = JTable::getInstance( 'Comment' , 'StreamTable' );
        $comment->load($id);

        if( !$my->authorise('stream.comment.delete', $comment) ){
            // No reason this code would ever get here!
            exit;
        }
        $oldComment = $comment->comment;
        $comment->delete();
        $this->_recalculateCommentCount($comment->stream_id, true);

        // Send back the original comment if it is the last one
        $data = array();
        $data['comment'] = $oldComment;

        header('Content-Type: text/json');
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit;
    }

    private function _recalculateCommentCount($message_id, $preventUpdate = false)
    {
        // Update stream stats. Recalculate the count
        $model = StreamFactory::getModel('stream');
        $stream = JTable::getInstance('Stream', 'StreamTable');
        $stream->load( $message_id ) ;
        $stream->setParam('comment_count', $model->countComments(array('stream_id' => $stream->id)));
        $stream->store( $preventUpdate );
    }

    /**
     *  Like a comment
     */
    public function like()
    {
        $user = JXFactory::getUser();
        $comment_id = JRequest::getVar('comment_id');

        $comment = JTable::getInstance('Comment', 'StreamTable');
        $comment->load($comment_id);

        $comment->like();
        $comment->store(true);

        $data = array();
        $data['label'] = JText::_('COM_STREAM_UNLIKE_LABEL');
        $data['count'] = $comment->getLikeCount();

        header('Content-Type: text/json');
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit;
    }

    /**
     * Unlike a comment
     */
    public function unlike()
    {
        $user = JXFactory::getUser();
        $comment_id = JRequest::getVar('comment_id');

        $comment = JTable::getInstance('Comment', 'StreamTable');
        $comment->load($comment_id);
        $comment->unlike();

        $comment->store(true);

        $data = array();
        $data['label'] = JText::_('COM_STREAM_LIKE_LABEL');
        $data['count'] = $comment->getLikeCount();

        header('Content-Type: text/json');
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit;
    }

    /**
     * Get all current likes
     */
    public function showlikes()
    {
        $comment_id = JRequest::getVar('comment_id');
        $comment = JTable::getInstance('Comment', 'StreamTable');
        $comment->load($comment_id);

        $likes = ($comment->likes) ? explode(',', $comment->likes ) : null;
        $likeUsers = array();
        $likesHTML = '';
        if ($likes) {
            foreach ($likes as $key => $val) {
                $likeUsers[] = JXFactory::getUser($val)->name;
            }

            $likesHTML = implode(", ", $likeUsers);
            $likesHTML = JXString::isPlural(count($likeUsers)) ? JText::sprintf('COM_STREAM_LIKE_THIS_MANY_LIST', $likesHTML) : JText::sprintf('COM_STREAM_LIKE_THIS_LIST', $likesHTML);
        }

        $data['likes'] = $likesHTML;

        header('Content-Type: text/json');
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: From past experience with Joomla, half the code in that ecosystem is just as bad. (The other half is worse.) It will be easier to just disable the notices (check the Joomla backend, server settings or similar) than to patch every instance of this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's happened here is that this function has been called statically:

```
StreamComment::showall(); // Static Call
```

But it's defined as a non-static method, which means PHP is expecting it to be called like this:

```
$obj = new StreamComment();
$obj->showall(); // Dynamic Call
```

If this is the only place this method is called, or it's consistently called statically, you can fix this by redefining the method as static:

```
public static function showall() // Added the "static" keyword
{
    // [..code..]
}
```

Hope this helps :) x

Comment: Thanks for your response. When I changed it to static as you suggested I get the following error:

Strict Standards: Non-static method StreamComment::getCommentsHTML() should not be called statically in C:\Program Files\Ampps\www\social\components\com_stream\controllers\comment.php on line 31

Comment: Looks like they've made the same mistake for `StreamComment::getCommentsHTML`. Try redeclaring that as static too? x

Comment: How do I do that for StreamComment::getCommentsHTML?

Comment: Same way we updated `showall`. Find `getCommentsHTML`'s declaration in that file (something like `public function getCommentsHTML()`) and add the `static` keyword. x

Comment: Have you got the class file for `StreamComment` anywhere?

Comment: I've added the complete code for comment.php to my original question up there. There is a "class StreamControllerComment extends JController" in the beginning of it and there are many "public function" in the comment.php file. Not sure what to do.

Comment: The problem is in a class called `StreamComment`, so `StreamControllerComment` is not the class we want. Try to find where `StreamComment` is defined.

Comment: You are a genius! I found "public function getCommentsHTML($stream_id)" in another file and added "static" to it and the error is gone now! THANK YOU VERY MUCH :)

Comment: @EmilyShepherd Thanks for helping answer a Joomla question. Did you know that we are getting really close to a dedicated Joomla site: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58842/joomla? Commit and help us get the beta site launched!